# Where can I find documentation on coding the 'target' value for an http plugin to Logstash?

Tags: logstash

I'm getting the following error in my logstash log:

`ECS compatibility is enabled but`target`option was not specified. This may cause fields to be set at the top-level of the event where they are likely to clash with the Elastic Common Schema. It is recommended to set the`target `option to avoid potential schema conflicts (if your data is ECS compliant or non-conflicting, feel free to ignore this message)`

My logstash config file currently looks like this:

`

```
input {
  http {
    port => 3333
    codec => json
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  }
`
```

Can someone point me to a description of how to code the 'target' option please?

See error log above for details

Answer (score 0):

`target` is an option on the json codec, not the http input. It is documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json.html#plugins-codecs-json-target). Try

```
http { port => 3333 codec => json { target => "[document]" } }
```